# Embedding an array of UIViewControllers within a UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I'm attempting to embed an array of UIViewControllers within a `UIViewController` with the UIViewControllers view having specific sizes & positions within the `UIViewController` view. What I'm finding is the child UIViewControllers with their view having other than origin (0, 0) to do not appear on the the screen. In the parent ViewController I have added subviews to accommodate this collage of child controllers. It becomes apparent in the child ViewControllers, that the view frames have the origin offset declared in the parent ViewController. I've tried to introduce some constraints for the top/left and dimensions of each child view, but this doesn't seem to make a difference.
All the advice I see on this topic seems to show examples with only one child view controller.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSUInteger i = 0;
    for(PlotInfo *plotinfo in _plot.plots)
    {
        switch([plotinfo.PlotType integerValue])
        {
            case SWPlotTypesScatterPlot:
            {
                NSUInteger index = [self indexInViewControllers:scatterPlotViewControllers ForPartition:[plotinfo.PartitionIndex integerValue]];
                if(index == NSNotFound)
                {
                    ScatterPlotViewController *scatterPlotViewController = (ScatterPlotViewController*)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"segueScatterPlotView"];
                    scatterPlotViewController.currentPlot = currentPlot;
                    scatterPlotViewController.delegate = self.delegateScatterPlot;
                    plotViewController = scatterPlotViewController;

                    [scatterPlotViewControllers addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:scatterPlotViewController, kViewController, plotinfo.PartitionIndex, kPartitionIndex, [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:i]], kActiveIDs, nil]];

                    scatterPlotViewController.view.frame = [self frameForChildController:[plotinfo.PartitionIndex integerValue]];
                    [self.view addSubview:scatterPlotViewController.view];
                    [self addChildViewController:scatterPlotViewController];

                    [self initConstraintsToSubView:scatterPlotViewController.view];


    //                    scatterPlotViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, scatterPlotViewController.view.frame.size.width, scatterPlotViewController.view.frame.size.height);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        NSMutableDictionary *dict = (NSMutableDictionary*)[scatterPlotViewControllers objectAtIndex:index];
                        NSMutableArray *newActiveIDs = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:(NSMutableArray*)[dict objectForKey:kActiveIDs]];
                        [newActiveIDs addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:i]];
                        [dict setObject:newActiveIDs forKey:kActiveIDs];
                    }
                }
                    break;
    // ………….                
                default:
                    break;
            }
            i++;
        }

        if([scatterPlotViewControllers count] > 0)
        {
            for(NSDictionary *dict in scatterPlotViewControllers)
            {
                ScatterPlotViewController *scatterPlotViewController = (ScatterPlotViewController*)[dict objectForKey:kViewController];
                scatterPlotViewController.activeIDs = [NSArray arrayWithArray:(NSMutableArray*)[dict objectForKey:kActiveIDs]];
                [scatterPlotViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
            }
        }
        // ………….
        [self updateViewConstraints];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
// ………..

    if([scatterPlotViewControllers count] > 0)
    {
        for(NSDictionary *dict in scatterPlotViewControllers)
        {
            ScatterPlotViewController *scatterPlotViewController = (ScatterPlotViewController*)[dict objectForKey:kViewController];
            [scatterPlotViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
            [scatterPlotViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
            [scatterPlotViewController removeFromParentViewController];
        }
    }
//…………
    differentTypesOfPlots = nil;
    barChartViewControllers = nil;
    pieChartViewControllers = nil;
    polarPlotViewControllers = nil;
    scatterPlotViewControllers = nil;
}


- (CGRect)frameForChildController:(NSUInteger)partitionIndex
{
    CGRect frameRect = CGRectZero;
    if(partitionIndex < [plotPartitionInformation count])
    {
        PartitionCell *cell = (PartitionCell *)[plotPartitionInformation objectAtIndex:partitionIndex];
        CGFloat heightFactor = self.view.bounds.size.height / cell.refHeight;
        CGFloat widthFactor = self.view.bounds.size.width / cell.refWidth;
        frameRect = CGRectMake(cell.xorigin*widthFactor, cell.yorigin*heightFactor, cell.width*widthFactor, cell.height*heightFactor);
    }

    return frameRect;
}

- (NSUInteger)indexInViewControllers:(NSMutableArray*)array ForPartition:(NSUInteger)index
{
    return [array indexOfObjectPassingTest:
            ^BOOL(NSDictionary *dict, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
            {
                return [(NSNumber*)[dict objectForKey:@"PartitionIndex"] integerValue] == index;
            }
            ];
}

- (void)initConstraintsToSubView:(UIView*)childView
{
    childView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    //Leading
    NSLayoutConstraint *leading = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:childView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0f constant:childView.frame.origin.x];

    //Bottom
    NSLayoutConstraint *top =[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:childView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0f constant:childView.frame.origin.y];

    //Height to be fixed for SubView same as AdHeight
    NSLayoutConstraint *height = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:childView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:0 multiplier:0 constant:childView.frame.size.height];
    //Height to be fixed for SubView same as AdHeight
    NSLayoutConstraint *width = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:childView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:0 multiplier:0 constant:childView.frame.size.width];

    [self.view addConstraint:leading];
    [self.view addConstraint:top];
    [childView addConstraint:height];
    [childView addConstraint:width];
}
```

Comment: This working completely depends on the origin set for the cell. The coordinates need to be zero relative in the space of the parent view. I don't see the definition of the appropriate structure that would let me know how you have created that origin value

Comment: The origin values and dimensions are determined in the routine ` - (CGRect)frameForChildController:(NSUInteger)partitionIndex`, these dimensions are created from elsewhere in my app, however all the dimensions and origins are factored to locate within the parent self.view.bounds and are zero relative. As a check I have generated a UIImage, using the origins and dimensions of each child view, and the resultant image reproduces a collage of views as I would like to see on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I was defining the graphing subview frame within my child ViewControllers view with the child's self.view frame. When I change the graphing subview's frame origin to (0,0), I solve my problem.